# En/Decrypting an In/Output stream in Java?

Tags: java, security, encryption, stream

is there any way to encrypt and decrypt an input and output stream in Java?
Thanks

Comment: CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream

Comment: In addition to using encryption I suggest using compression.  This will make the stream a) slightly harder to decrypt as it will be more random b) smaller c) possibly faster if you get a decent compression ratio.  I suggest using the Deflator and Inflator streams.

Comment: [Here a full sample](https://gist.github.com/mageddo/7286d1c51bdb8877b4124ddacb492ac3) of how to Encrypt And Decrypt with stream

Comment: "not a real question" bruh

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look for CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream.

> A **CipherInputStream** is composed of an InputStream and a Cipher so that read() methods return data that are read in from the underlying InputStream but have been additionally processed by the Cipher. The Cipher must be fully initialized before being used by a CipherInputStream.
>
> For example, if the Cipher is initialized for decryption, the CipherInputStream will attempt to read in data and decrypt them, before returning the decrypted data.
>
> This class adheres strictly to the semantics, especially the failure semantics, of its ancestor classes java.io.FilterInputStream and java.io.InputStream. This class has exactly those methods specified in its ancestor classes, and overrides them all. Moreover, this class catches all exceptions that are not thrown by its ancestor classes. In particular, the skip method skips, and the available method counts only data that have been processed by the encapsulated Cipher.
>
> It is crucial for a programmer using this class not to use methods that are not defined or overriden in this class (such as a new method or constructor that is later added to one of the super classes), because the design and implementation of those methods are unlikely to have considered security impact with regard to CipherInputStream.

---

> A **CipherOutputStream** is composed of an OutputStream and a Cipher so that write() methods first process the data before writing them out to the underlying OutputStream. The cipher must be fully initialized before being used by a CipherOutputStream.
>
> For example, if the cipher is initialized for encryption, the CipherOutputStream will attempt to encrypt data before writing out the encrypted data.
>
> This class adheres strictly to the semantics, especially the failure semantics, of its ancestor classes java.io.OutputStream and java.io.FilterOutputStream. This class has exactly those methods specified in its ancestor classes, and overrides them all. Moreover, this class catches all exceptions that are not thrown by its ancestor classes.
>
> It is crucial for a programmer using this class not to use methods that are not defined or overriden in this class (such as a new method or constructor that is later added to one of the super classes), because the design and implementation of those methods are unlikely to have considered security impact with regard to CipherOutputStream.

Comment: man, don't reward questions like this from people who clearly have put _no_ effort into anything.

Comment: Well I knew that this classes exists, but I needed 2 minutes to find them. Sometimes it is difficult to find the right key words.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CipherOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) and [CipherInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) to encrypt or decrypt Input/OutputStreams